# Is imported code in webpack guarantee to fully execute before anything else?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, es6-modules, web-frontend

Let's say I have a module `A` that is imported by module `B` in a `webpack` project.

`A.js`

```
const variable = synchronousGetData()

export function exportedFunction() {
  // do some work with variable
}
```

`B.js`

```
import { exportedFunction } from 'A'

exportedFunction()
```

Is `variable` guaranteed to be fully instantiated (e.g. the synchronous work will have been done and assigned to `variable` via `synchronousGetData()`?)

I can only think of the case where module `A` requires `B` as well, in which case you have a circular dependency, and this could throw things off, correct? But if no circular dependency is present then does the above guarantee exist?

Comment: The spec dictates that a module is completely evaluated before its exports are made available to another module. If webpack wouldn't do that for whatever reason, it's a bug.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I'll dig further into the spec to find the specific clause. Do you know what will happen in the case of a circular dependency? Is it deterministic?